# Why was my question about jQuery keypress events closed as not a real question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Someone thought that my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827408/whats-the-theory-behind-jquery-keypress-keydown-keyup-black-magic-on-macs) was an attempt at a discussion. It was not. I was asking for specific answers about books or other documentation that would help me with Javascript event handlers. I even went back and edited the question to make it more question-y. It hasn't been reopened. Not that I would care, but I got a notice saying that my reputation had been besmirched by the closing of this question. Is there any recourse?

Comment: I agree with the closing reason; however, you got three decent answers already. And don't worry about a closing here and there; it's not a big deal, really.

Comment: *"I got a notice saying that my reputation had been besmirched by the closing of this question"* What exactly do you mean by that? What notice?

Comment: Lol, you lose a few rep points if you get downvoted (none at all if the question just got closed); "my reputation had been besmirched" is a bit overly dramatic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You say:

> I was asking for specific answers about books or other documentation that would help me with Javascript event handlers.

And in your question you ask

> Could someone help me to figure out which document I need to read in order to more effectively use these events?

And that really is the problem. We don't want to recommend books or link to documentation. We don't do book recommendations. Those are off-topic. And we don't want to gather answers which are nothing more than links to documents.

In summary, we want to help you solve your problems. Not merely link to outside resources that might help you solve your problems.

Think of it like this: Future visitors with a similar problem should read the question and find an answer. Not merely information on where they might possibly find an answer. And the latter is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

- **`What's the theory?`** in the title  makes this look not constructive when first looking at it. Your title is the most important part of the question, and the one you have kind of looks like you're starting a discussion, which is bad.
- All of your *actual* questions are basically asking for links to documentation. Try rephrasing it to get people to explain the difference between them. "Asking for links" is a very typical reason for closing questions. Likely someone will reference the documentation in their answer to the question and link it there, combined with relevant information *here on the site*, rather than just a link.
- Finally, the key of your question, *the actual problem you're facing*:

  > I use jQuery to build an input form and insert it into my document. It works just fine, mostly. I want the form to respond to the keyboard like most other input forms I see out there: the esc key should dismiss the form the same as clicking the cancel button, and because the form has a < textarea > on it, cmd+enter should be the same as clicking the ok button. It seems simple enough to use the keypress event.

  You need to focus on this part a little more. You *should* provide code for this, at least for your first attempt or the key commands that you think make most sense for what you're trying to achieve. Not everyone enjoys reading through text, and some people may be able to help you better being able to see an example of code you're working with. It could simply be that you're not calling functions or keys correctly, in which case we could explain them to you but it'd still be a wild goose hunt trying to solve the actual problem.